# How to transpose a column that has many rows

Tags: excel

I'm trying to take a column and transpose the rows into columns. I've read that I should copy the column and then use the paste option called "Transpose". Though when I try, I'm receiving this error

> you can't paste this here because the copy area and paste area aren't the same size

The column I'm trying to transpose has many rows, so I figured that I just needed to add the needed amount of columns myself. I've tried using Home>Insert'ing columns but the sheet size doesn't actually seem to be changing. I know that when I scroll over, however, columns are automatically generated. I'm not sure why the Transpose couldn't also generate the amount of columns it needs, but I guess that's besides the point. What should I do here?

Comment: No need to add columns, try only selecting one cell when pasting

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Still getting that error with only one cell selected :/

Comment: Are you selecting the entire column (i.e. by clicking on the column name at the top) or just the cells with content? Do the latter

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Yeah I'm just selecting a single cell (A1 for example)

Comment: When copying, only select those cells you want to copy, not the entire column. When pasting only select one cell. Make sure you don't have merged cells anywhere

Comment: How many rows is ***many rows***?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Oh! That's probably it, yes I was copying the entire column.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thank you so much, just tried it and it worked!